# Get string and number with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in javascript like this:

> some string 27

or it could be

> some string

or

> string 123

or even

> string 23A - or - string 23 A

So in other words, it's always a string. Sometimes it ends with a number, sometimes not. And sometimes the number has a letter (only one) at the end.

Now the problem is, that I have to split this string. I need the string and number (including the letter if there's one) stored in two variables. Like in:

> some string 27

var str = "some string"
var number = 27;

I probably need to do this with regex. But i have no idea how.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: If it is `some string 27 A` how do you want your 2 variables to be?

Comment: @anubhava Then it should still consist of two variables. ***var str = "some string"*** and ***var number = "27 A"***

Comment: well `"27 A"` is not really a number, can you use some better naming variable pls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this regex:

```
var arr = s.match(/^(\D+?)\s*(\d+(?:\s+[A-Z])?)$/i);
```

Then use:

```
var str = arr[1];
var number = arr[2];
```

Assuming s is your variable containing original text;

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a function:

```
function splitStringsNumbers(str)
{
    return 
    {
         Numbers: str.match(/[0-9]+/g)
         Strings: str.match(/^[0-9]+/g)
    }
}
```

Now use it like this:

```
var obj = splitStringsNumbers("string 23A")
console.log(obj.Strings[0]); //print string
console.log(obj.Numbers[0]); //print 23
console.log(obj.Numbers[1]); //print A
```

If you want the nubmer as numeric variable,
you could use `parseInt(str)`.
Also, this solution works only for Integers, for using it with floats (like string 23.4A) you need to change a bit the regex.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you provided regex should be:

```
/(.*) (\d+ ?[A-Z]?)$/i
```

Anything can be string.
Number is anchored to the end, it is separated from string by single space, space and letter at the end are optional.

```
var v='some string 27';
var arr = v.match(/(.*) (\d+ ?[A-Z]?)$/i);
var str = arr[1];
var num = arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
/^([^\d]*)(\d+\s*[a-z]?)?$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
var r = new RegExp("/[0-9]+\w?/");
var s = "some letters 125a";
console.log(s.match(r));
```